# Check a non-projective morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

The following is from the wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_morphism

> Projective morphisms are proper, but not all proper morphisms are
>   projective. For example, it can be shown that the scheme obtained by
>   contracting two disjoint projective lines in some **P**$^3$ to one is a
>   proper, but non-projective variety.

How to check it is non-projective? And I think it should be a morphism, how does it become a variety?

Comment: For any variety $X$ over a field $k$, to say that $X$ is proper means exactly that the morphism $X \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec} k$ is proper. For the first question, I don't know: did you read the paper cited in the Wikipedia article? Another example is given in Appendix A of Hartshorne: there the idea is to construct a proper threefold with two curves $C$, $C'$ on it such that $C \equiv -C'$ (in the sense of numerical equivalence). This can never happen on a projective variety, because there is an ample divisor.

Comment: But here the morphism is to one line, not to the Spec k, how does it become a variety? The paper cited in the Wikipedia article is not in English, so I do not read it.

Comment: No, I think you are misunderstanding the quoted text. "Contracting two disjoint lines to one" does not mean that we are considering a morphism to a line, it means that we are glueing two lines together. (I agree the wording is not very clear.)

Comment: Actually I just read the quoted article (Ferrand, _Conducteur, descente, et pincement_) and Wikipedia's description of the counterxample is incorrect: one should glue a line and a conic in $\mathbf P^3$, not two lines.

Comment: Oh, that is language problem. I want to know the property of projective morphism( or scheme), which can distinguish something are non-projective.

Comment: In fact, I do not know much about geometry in the scheme version. Does the ample divisor you have said means ample sheaf(in wiki it is ample linear bundle)? And ... projective variety has no ample divisor?